# Stuck at "Checking info" when trying to add an account to a new Android Studio Virtual device

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, virtualbox

I am trying to add an account to my new Android STudio virtual device, but when I click on Google from the account options it shows a blue screen with "Checking info..." message. Stuck here as it was checking for a few minutes now.

PS: I received an error "Error communicating with Google Services" and that is it...